# How to run code in React function component before first render, like in the constructor of a class component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a piece of code in React Native that currently runs on app start. Within a class component constructor. It checks a bunch of conditions using the React Navigation state and then navigates somewhere.

```
class MyComponent<Props> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    // Some initialization code
  }
}
```

I refactored it to use hooks using both `useEffect` and `useLayoutEffect`, but the code run now seems to happen only after the initial rendering, causing a flicker of another screen before the navigation takes place.

```
function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Do some stuff
  }, []);  

  return null;
}
```

Is there some equivalent to the class constructor that runs before rendering in function components?

Comment: *I refactored it to use hooks using both useEffect and useLayoutEffect, but the navigation now seems to happen only after the initial rendering, causing a flicker of another screen before the navigation takes place.* Pretty hard to debug code we can't see

Comment: you can use a splash screen, then call `SplashScreen.hide()` when your app is ready - https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I figured out a solution.

Before, I'd written the code this way:

```
function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Do some stuff
  }, []);  

  return null;
}
```

Turns out the equivalent is just running your code in the function itself, since that runs before the actual rendering-to-screen.

```
function MyComponent() {
  const initializedRef = useRef(false);
  if (!initializedRef.current) {
    initializedRef.current = true;
    // Do some stuff
  }

  return null;
}
```

This seems to be as fast as the run-in-constructor code I used to have.